Can't make Spring Boot Social Login tutorial work
I am trying to follow this tutorial https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/guides/how-to-social-login.html on how to configure spring security to work with social login.
I followed the steps but I am getting the following error:
Parameter 0 of method setFilterChains in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClientRepository' that could not be found.

I created an app in Github and set the callback url to http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/github
This is what my application.yml looks like:
okta:
  base-url: http://localhost:8080

spring:
  application:
    name: myapp
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          github:
            clientId: ${GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}
            clientSecret: ${GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}
            scope:
              - openid
              - profile
              - email
        provider:
          okta:
            authorization-uri: ${okta.base-url}/oauth2/v1/authorize
            token-uri: ${okta.base-url}/oauth2/v1/token
            user-info-uri: ${okta.base-url}/oauth2/v1/userinfo
            jwk-set-uri: ${okta.base-url}/oauth2/v1/keys
            user-name-attribute: sub


I also set the SecurityConfig as described in the tutorial, any idea why am I getting that error?

have you defined GITHUB_CLIENT_ID and GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET

yes, I have defined them as environment variables

Your question is missing dependencies with versions (your pom or Gradle file)
